# Operator overloading is happening in this question but the number of arguments and type is same

Tags: c++, c++11

The following code should generate compilation error according to me. Because I think the compiler might be confused to know which foo() to call.

```
#include <iostream> 

typedef long long ll;

void foo(unsigned ll) {
    std::cout << "1";
}

void foo(unsigned long long) {
    std::cout << "2";
}

int main() {
    foo(2ull);
}
```

I was expecting the compiler to treat `foo(unsigned ll)` as `foo(unsigned long long)`.

Comment: Function overloading :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no operator overloading happening in this code. And this code should compile just fine. `typedef`s are not macros. They don't just perform simple textual replacement of tokens. A `typedef` introduces an alternative name for a type that can be used anywhere the name of a type can be used. This:

```
void foo(unsigned ll)
```

is a function named foo that takes a single argument of type `unsigned int` and returns `void`. The name of the first parameter is `ll`. Since `unsigned` already is a *type-specifier* (it's shorthand for `unsigned int`), the identifier `ll` following the `unsigned` in the parameter declaration is treated as the name of the entity being declared. This means there are two overloads for `foo` in your code above, the first one being `foo(unsigned int)` and the second one `foo(unsigned long long)`. When you call

```
foo(2ull);
```

overload resolution will pick `foo(unsigned long long)` since the type of the argument `2ull` is `unsigned long long`, which is an exact match for `foo(unsigned long long)`…

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with this code. Typedef is used to create aliases to existing types. It doesn't interchange ll with long long in foo(unsigned ll).
Basically it treats ll as a parameter here and type is unsigned int. But in the second foo() parameter type is unsigned long long.

Your code will show compilation error if you use #define ll long long instead of
typedef long long ll;